# Specify URL instead of IP:port in network endpoints for applications behind reverse proxy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

We are using GCP external HTTPS load balancer, architecture is shown in the diagram below. The primary use of LB is redirecting users to static error site (hosted on Cloud Storage bucket) in case CE instance is down, Traefik crashes on CE, Docker crashes on CE, etc.

We have 4 backend services defined on load balancer:

1. `static-error-page` backend bucket
2. `blog-backend-service`, `gallery-backend-service` and `shop-backend-service` zonal network endpoint groups

Then, we defined host and path rules so that:

1. `https://blog.company.com` -> `blog-backend-service`
2. `https://gallery.company.com` -> `gallery-backend-service`
3. `https://shop.company.com` -> `shop-backend-service`
4. `All unmatched (default)` -> `static-error-page`

Each zonal network endpoint group (`blog-backend-service`, `gallery-backend-service` and `shop-backend-service`) has just 1 endpoint defined: `192.168.171:443` (`192.168.171.3` is internal IP of CE instance).

However, since my websites are served behind reverse proxy (Traefik), specifying `IP:port` combination in network endpoint is useless because they all have the same `IP:port`. I would like to specify URL instead of `IP:port` in network endpoint (that way network endpoint would also show correct health status if website is down, it always reports *healthy* now, even if application is down).

Is it possible to specify URL instead of `IP:port` in network endpoint? If not, what are my alternatives?

[image]

Comment: did you manage to find out the answer for this?

Comment: @Basit No, unfortunately not. If you discover anything useful, I will be happy if you post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using treafik, you can use Google API Gateway which was meant to do that job, while you can still use the load balancer behind it.